# update date format field with current datetimestamp via configparser module

Tags: python-3.x, configparser

I am using interpolation feature of configparser module. My problem is for the value which is referred across different sections, I would like it to have date or datetime as part of its value. Below is what I could come up with, while it does my job I feel that there could be a better and elegant way to handle this.

```
import configparser
from io import StringIO
import datetime


def update_tmstmp_value(config_string):
    fo = StringIO(config_string)
    data = ''
    for line in fo.readlines():
        if line.startswith('tmstmp'):
            key, tmstmp_str = line.strip().split('=')
            try:
                value = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(tmstmp_str)
            except ValueError:
                value = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
            data += key + '=' + value + '\n'
        else:
            data += line
    return data


config_data = """
[DEFAULT]
tmstmp=%Y%m%d
type=REPLACE_ME_%(tmstmp)s

[section1]
item1=val1_%(type)s
item2=val2

[section2]
item3=val3_%(type)s
item4=val4
"""

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
modified_config_data = update_tmstmp_value(config_data)
config.read_string(modified_config_data)
print(config.items('section1'))
```

**Output:**

```
[('tmstmp', '20190402'), ('type', 'REPLACE_ME_20190402'), ('item1', 'val1_REPLACE_ME_20190402'), ('item2', 'val2')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following functions within a wrapper class for the ConfigParser that does pretty much what you are trying to do.

This way I can prepend the date to any of the option=vars that I want to.

```
    def get_date():
        """
        Sets up a date formatted string.

        :return: Date string
        """
        return datetime.now().strftime("%Y%b%d")

    def prepend_date_to_var(self, sect, option):
        """
        Function that allows the ability to prepend a
        date to a section variable.

        :param sect: INI section to look for variable
        :param option: INI search variable under INI section
        :return: Date is prepended to variable
        """
        if self.config_parser.get(sect, option):
            var = self.config_parser.get(sect, option)
            var_with_date = var + '_' + self.get_date()
            self.config_parser.set(sect, option, var_with_date)
```